# recurrence relation question.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

I have this expression: $I_{n} = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{2-x} dx$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$
I have been asked to show that by writing $x^n = x^{n-1} (2-(2-x))$ that the recurrence relation $I_{n+1} = 2I_n - \frac{1}{n} $
After hours of rearranging and substituting I keep going round in circles. Has anyone got any ideas of what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

$$I_{n+1}-2I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}-2x^{n-1}}{2-x}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(2-x)}{2-x}dx=-\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx\text{ as }2-x\ne0$$

Use $$\int x^m dx=\begin{cases} \ln x &\mbox{if } m =-1 \\
 \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}& \mbox{else where }\end{cases}$$